# Why don’t I have a option for wireless internet?

Tags: windows-10

I only have a Ethernet adapter option. I have googled a lot and nothing has worked . There is no WiFi option in the Network & Internet settings. It’s a gaming pc I built it myself.

Comment: What kind of computer do you have?  make & model Right now its too vague to give a good answer.

Comment: It’s a gaming pc I’m not really good with computers because I’m new with it so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a USB to wifi adapter, and plug it into, an available USB port.